# How to unshard a mongoDB collection in verison 3.6?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, sharding

I have a mongoDB sharding configuration with 3 shards each with 2 nodes. I have sharded 2 collections as of now

1. order
2. error

Now I came to a stage to unshard my error collection. I don't want to have a new shard key and all. I just want to unshard that collection so that all the documents reside within the primary shard. How can I do that?
I know I need to move all the chunks to primary. But if someone could help me with the steps that I need to follow it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Few options here:

1. mongodump/mongorestore from mongos ( if your database is relatively small and down time is possible this maybe best option )
2. Upgrade to latest mongod 6.0 or at least 4.2 then you have some nice official commands to unshard: [remove shards](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/remove-shards-from-cluster/)
3. 3.6-> Move chunks manually and clean afterwards.